# How to show official sphinx examples and documentation of modules in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am looking at a builtin package that is unfamiliar to me : `csv` (I usually use either `pandas.read_csv` or `numpy.gettext`).  Is there a quick documentation feature in `pycharm` to show official `sphinx` docs for a module?   I tried opening the `csv` builtin source and right clicking and see this

[image]

There does not seem to be any `documentation` related links in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick Documentation**

I tried a general search for `documentation` in `Pycharm` `Search for any`. The most relevant (first two) hits

[image]

The `Show Documentation` goes to the main page of `python docs` - which is not the context-sensitive information being sought.

The **`Quick Documentation`** - either `CTL-J` or `View|Quick Documenation - *is* what I was seeking.  The most effective method is to select the module name in the header and then hit` CTL-J`. In the` csv`module I selected`csv`:

[image]

A pop-up shows: notice at the bottom the *link to the *specific* module on csv.org* :

[image]

Clicking on that link brings us to where we wanted to go:

[image]